# Gimp: remove grey background after applying ripple effect

Tags: animation, gimp, ripple

When I select text layer and then apply ripple effect (Filter -> Animations ->Ripple) resulted image has grey background.
Can I remove this background or change its colour?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a single-colored background in Gimp using the [color selection tool](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-by-color-select.html).  Here's a [screen cast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWJ8sxQ_494&feature=youtu.be) showing how to do it.